# In Angular 5, formdata.has is not working in IE browser

Tags: angular

```
  if (this.formData.has('Apple')) {
      this.formData.delete('Apple');          
   }
```

> I am getting below error
>       "Object doesn't support property or method 'has'"
>       when i am trying to remove document using IE 11 Browser.But It is working fine with chrome.
>       Please provide any alternate solution to work this in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

FormData don't support `has` in IE:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

You can use this polyfill to fix this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/formdata-polyfill

Comment: Yes.I have uncommented that.Even though its not working.

Comment: @srikasi what is type of your `this.formData`?

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9

Check this out may be this can help

Comment: @ Patryk Uszyński  this.formData = new FormData(); which i used to upload files.

Comment: @srikasi meaby you call `.has` before `this.formData` initialziation. Try this: `if (this.formData && this.formData.has('Apple')) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `polyfills.ts` at root and following lines are not commented

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: I  uncommented these lines from polyfills.ts.Even though its not working. Can you please provide any alternate solution to this to work in IE11 Browser.